# Некорректно работает код jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Возникла проблема с выплывающим меню. Код представлен ниже. При нажатии на кнопку, скрипт, вроде, начинает работать, но сразу же прекращается и ломается. Не могу понять, в чем дело.

```js
$(".main-nav__button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    $(this).toggleClass("main-nav__button--active");
    $(".main-nav").toggleClass("main-nav--active");
    $(".main-nav__list").toggleClass("main-nav__list--active");
});
```

```css
.main-nav__button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.main-nav__button span,
.main-nav__button span::before,
.main-nav__button span::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #000;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    right: 0;
}
.main-nav__button span::before,
.main-nav__button span::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.main-nav__button span::before {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.main-nav__button span::after {
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
.main-nav__button--active span{
    height: 0;
}
.main-nav__button--active span::before,
.main-nav__button--active span::after {
    width: 30px;
}
.main-nav__button--active span::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.main-nav__button--active span::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.main-nav__list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    // transition: 0.3s;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: scaleY(0) translateY(-40%);
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-nav__list--active {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    transform: scaleY(1)  translateY(0%);
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
.main-nav--active {
    background-color: #283645;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.main-nav__list li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0 15px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #485461;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.main-nav__list a{
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="page-header__nav main-nav">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <a href="" class="main-nav__button">
                    <span></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="main-nav__list">
                <li class="main-nav__item">
                    <a>Главная</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav__item">
                    <a href="gallery.html">Фотографии</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav__item">
                    <a href="competition.html">Конкурс</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.preventDefault(); // я добавил () такой синтаксис правильный.

```js
$(".main-nav__button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // ()
    $(this).toggleClass("main-nav__button--active");
    $(".main-nav").toggleClass("main-nav--active");
    $(".main-nav__list").toggleClass("main-nav__list--active");
});
```

```css
.main-nav__button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.main-nav__button span,
.main-nav__button span::before,
.main-nav__button span::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #000;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    right: 0;
}
.main-nav__button span::before,
.main-nav__button span::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.main-nav__button span::before {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.main-nav__button span::after {
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
.main-nav__button--active span{
    height: 0;
}
.main-nav__button--active span::before,
.main-nav__button--active span::after {
    width: 30px;
}
.main-nav__button--active span::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.main-nav__button--active span::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.main-nav__list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    // transition: 0.3s;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: scaleY(0) translateY(-40%);
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-nav__list--active {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    transform: scaleY(1)  translateY(0%);
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
.main-nav--active {
    background-color: #283645;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.main-nav__list li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0 15px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #485461;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.main-nav__list a{
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="page-header__nav main-nav">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <a href="" class="main-nav__button">
                    <span></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="main-nav__list">
                <li class="main-nav__item">
                    <a>Главная</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav__item">
                    <a href="gallery.html">Фотографии</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-nav__item">
                    <a href="competition.html">Конкурс</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить пояснений, чем ваш код отличается от кода ТС.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); // я добавил () скорее всего такой синтаксис правильный. 
Прост если честно пока не особо силен, в js (jQuery).
Я просто в песке открыл код ТСа и загуглил че такое  preventDefault  и гляул примеры burger menu , везде в примерах были ();

Comment: Спасибо,я так понял, из-за того, что не добавил скобки к этому, не знаю как правильно назвать, пусть будет "событию", код работал неправильно. А в ответе нижу,если поменял на див,то preventDefault просто был и не нужен, так как отменять нечего.

Comment: Надо добавить эту информацию в ответ, а не в комментариях писать. @iMur preventDefault - это метод. Его надо вызывать.

Comment: Ок буду знать, ток зарегался тут.
непонятно ток как переносы строки делать, чтобы красиво ответы выглядили.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй вот так: js

```
$().ready(function() {
  $(".main-nav__button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    $(this).toggleClass("main-nav__button--active");
    $(".main-nav").toggleClass("main-nav--active");
    $(".main-nav__list").toggleClass("main-nav__list--active");
  });
});
```

а в html

```
<a href="" class="main-nav__button">
  <span></span>
</a>
```

замени на

```
<div class="main-nav__button">
  <span></span>
</div>
```